# If I keep running it in python, the following error appears

Tags: python, discord.py

```
2024-01-07 23:00:29 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <Buttons timeout=None children=3> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='잔액' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 621, in fetch
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1704636029398&recvWindow=10000&signature=51fa3e4dbcca2db31359b981094aa51306ab3f6e1434f9a8af68fb628cd587ce

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python crypto discord bot\main.py", line 64, in menu_balance
    await balance(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python crypto discord bot\main.py", line 42, in balance
    balance = binance.fetch_balance()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\binance.py", line 2560, in fetch_balance
    response = self.privateGetAccount(self.extend(request, query))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\types.py", line 34, in unbound_method
    return _self.request(self.path, self.api, self.method, params, config=self.config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\binance.py", line 8034, in request
    response = self.fetch2(path, api, method, params, headers, body, config)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 3333, in fetch2
    return self.fetch(request['url'], request['method'], request['headers'], request['body'])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 637, in fetch
    skip_further_error_handling = self.handle_errors(http_status_code, http_status_text, url, method, headers, http_response, json_response, request_headers, request_body)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\binance.py", line 8003, in handle_errors
    self.throw_exactly_matched_exception(self.exceptions['exact'], error, feedback)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 3673, in throw_exactly_matched_exception
    raise exact[string](message)
ccxt.base.errors.InvalidNonce: binance {"code":-1021,"msg":"Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time."}
```

```
from typing import Any, Optional
import discord
import os
import ccxt
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import View, button
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from colorama import Back, Fore, Style
from datetime import datetime


load_dotenv()



discord_token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
binance_api_key = os.getenv('BINANCE_API_KEY')
binance_api_secret_key = os.getenv('BINANCE_API_SECRET_KEY')

binance = ccxt.binance(config={
    'apiKey': binance_api_key,
    'secret': binance_api_secret_key,
    'enableRateLimit': True
})

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.activity.Game(name="/command"), status=discord.Status.online)
    print(f"{client.user.name} is loggen in.")

async def cryptobtn(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("txid조회하기")
    # https://docs-v2.blocksdk.com/ko/litecoin.html#3a5038a279

async def send(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("송금하기", ephemeral=True)
    # exchange.withdraw(code="modal", amount=100, address="", tag="")

async def balance(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    balance = binance.fetch_balance()

    embed = discord.Embed(title='코인 잔액', color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 255, 0))
    embed.add_field(name='LTC', value=f"코인수량: {balance['LTC']['free']}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='TRX', value=f"코인수량: {balance['TRX']['free']}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='USDT', value=f"코인수량: {balance['USDT']['free']}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='XRP', value=f"코인수량: {balance['XRP']['free']}", inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)


class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    @discord.ui.button(label='txid조회하기', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id='1')
    async def menu_txid(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, Button: discord.ui.Button):
        await cryptobtn(interaction)
    @discord.ui.button(label='송금', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id='2')
    async def menu_send(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, Button: discord.ui.Button):
        await send(interaction)
    @discord.ui.button(label='잔액', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id='3')
    async def menu_balance(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, Button: discord.ui.Button):
        await balance(interaction)


class PersistentViewBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        interts = discord.Intents().all()
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('/'), intents=interts)
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        self.add_view(Buttons())

client = PersistentViewBot()


@client.tree.command(name='coin', description="코인 관련 버튼 봇")
async def coin(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='코인봇', timestamp=datetime.now(), color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    embed.add_field(name='txid조회기능', value='txid를 입력후 조회합니다.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='코인송금기능', value='코인 종류와 코인 수량과 코인 주소를 입력하면 송금합니다.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='잔액조회기능', value='지갑의 잔액을 조회합니다.', inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=Buttons())


client.run(discord_token)
```

Comment: The mesage "Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time." might be a hint for solving this problem.